# How to create drawable folder in res?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-drawable

I am trying to create `drawable-hdpi`  `drawable-xxhdpi` `drawable-ldpi`folders for different screens but unable to create as it says the folders already exist but i can't see them also when trying to create `drawable-xxhdpi` folder on click nothing happens no folder's are create

Screenshots below

Can't see any `drawable-xhdpi` folder although it says it exist

[image]

Here on clicking OK nothing happens no folder is created

[image]

Comment: Move to file explorer at your project location and check if directory exist or not.

Comment: Change the view from "Android" to "Project" and browse the res folder.

Comment: If exist in File Explorer, try to copy some `.png` and you will see different folder in which you are willing to move the `.png`

Comment: @misterrai Please see my answer with screenshot you will get better understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it already exist.

you have to change the project structure

Click on top left dropdown where **Android** Appears.

Select **project** from this dropdown and you will be able to see all drawbale folders.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Its because you might not have any files inside your res/drawable-xxx folders

To access them, change your project navigation:

To do so, check the top left pane for some written as `1 Project` click on that or alternatively press `Alt+1` here, if you see the default selection will be `Android` with an android bot click on the two left-right arrow icons select `Project Files` and then navigate!

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to explicitly create the drawable folders for different resolutions.
Whenever you will add any image to the project's drawable folder, by clicking right on the drawable folder and pasting the image there, a dialog will open up, that will ask you to select from drawable-hdpi, drawable-mdpi, drawable-xhdpi, and drawable-xxhdpi. 
You can then select the suitable one from the drop down, and you will be able to see the distinctions within the drawable folder itself.